# Unable to click a button in webform

Tags: excel, vba

I can't seem to find a way to click on the button of a webpage, see below the html. It's `id="item_knopBer2"` i'm trying to get clicked. I spent hours trying all variants I could find here like: `FireEvent`, `querySelectorAll`, `querySelector` but tottaly frustrated noting works so far.

Please, somebody what am I missing here?

```
<span class="PrintHide spBerB tooltipL" id="item_knopBer2" title="knopberekening" style="padding-right: 14px; ">
                                    <input class="Knopber" onclick="wisSalSc(); this.className = 'KnopberActive'; javascript: ProformaVerslag('B');" 
                                    onmouseover="this.className='KnopberHover'" onmouseout="this.className='Knopber'" type="button" value='Berekenen'/>
</span>
```

Comment: Actually your code is missing: What code have you tried? Also see [mcve].

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. I added the macro below. Hope you can take a look at it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a span not a button. Fireevent wont work anymore. You must dispatch an event if it should work with an event. Try this:

```
Dim nodeItem_knopBer2 As Object

'Your code
'...

On Error Resume Next
Set nodeItem_knopBer2 = browser.document.getElementByID("item_knopBer2")
On Error GoTo 0

If Not nodeItem_knopBer2 Is Nothing Then
  Call TriggerEvent(browser.document, nodeItem_knopBer2, "click")
  'Maybe
  'Call TriggerEvent(browser.document, nodeItem_knopBer2, "onClick")
End If

'Rest of your code
'...
```

With this procedure you hand over the required event:

```
Private Sub TriggerEvent(htmlDocument As Object, htmlElementWithEvent As Object, eventType As String)

  Dim theEvent As Object

  htmlElementWithEvent.Focus
  Set theEvent = htmlDocument.createEvent("HTMLEvents")
  theEvent.initEvent eventType, True, False
  htmlElementWithEvent.dispatchEvent theEvent
End Sub
```

If that don't work you must post the url and your macro code.

Comment: I could not get the marco in as comment, so i've responded as an answer.